# Может, можно всё же-с прибавлять к римским цифрам наращения?

Tags: орфография

Мы знаем, например, что мы не прибавляем наращения к арабским цифрам, которые описывают года, века, даты (*Я рождён 6 мая*), но, когда нету названия, однако, месяца, века или года, мы должны прибавлять наращение (*А я – 7-го рождён, сэр*).

Может, то же и с римскими? Как правильно?

> Глаголы II спряжения имеют окончание *-ить*, а I – все остальные.

> Глаголы II спряжения имеют окончание *-ить*, а I-го – все остальные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя.

> Наращение не используется:
> <...>
> • Если число обозначено римской цифрой: *II Международная олимпиада школьников по русскому языку; IX конгресс, XXI век, Людовик XIV.*

Из [пособия](https://pedlib.ru/Books/4/0038/4_0038-124.shtml) для поступающих в вузы:

> Ко **II** спряжению относятся глаголы, которые в инфинитиве оканчиваются на -итъ. Например: молить, топить, клеить. Исключение составляют глаголы брить, стелить, зыбиться и зиждиться, которые относятся к **I** спряжению. Ко **II** спряжению относятся также семь глаголов на -еть (вертеть, смотреть, зависеть, ненавидеть, обидеть, видеть, терпеть) и четыре глагола на -ать (дышать, слышать, гнать, держать). Остальные глаголы с безударными окончаниями относятся к **I** спряжению: колоть, полоть, таять, сеять, веять, надеяться и др.

Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. (Современный русский язык: Учебник / Под редакцией Н. С. Валгиной):
*Глаголы хотеть, бежать (и производные от них) образуют смешанное спряжение (с окончаниями **I** и **II** спряжения...*

[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Comment: Но нет ни одного примера с тем, про что я говорю! Там после римских цифр всегда идёт существительное, а в моём случае – не идёт!

Comment: Для римских цифр нет разницы. Например, **Людовик XIV** — числительное идет *после* существительного, наращения нет.

Comment: Римма, что думаете об нововведении?

Comment: Смотрите ниже-с.

Answer (score 0):

> Глаголы II спряжения имеют окончание -*ить*, а I – все остальные.
>
> Глаголы II спряжения имеют окончание -*ить*, а I-го – все остальные.
>
> Как правильно?

Первый приведённый Вами пример, на мой взгляд, однозначно нехорош.

Второй, по-моему, читается значительно лучше (хотя и страдает некоторой неточностью формулировки!).

> Может, можно всё же-с прибавлять к римским цифрам наращения?

Традиционно при ответах на подобные вопросы ссылаются на рекомендации   «**Справочника издателя и автора**» Мильчина, в которых наращение после числительных, записанных римскими цифрами, не предусмотрено.

Но противоречит ли использование такого наращения **орфографическим правилам?** По-моему, нет. Если бы противоречило, авторы школьных пособий его бы не использовали.

Приведу пару фото, сделанных с одного из последних изданий очень-очень известного пособия  [**Громов С.А. «Русский язык. Курс практической грамотности для старшеклассников и абитуриентов». М., 2019**]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это просто не по-нормальному написанные статьи из учебников. Римма, думаю, права.

Comment: А у Вас первый пример **по-нормальному** написан: «Глаголы II спряжения имеют окончание -ить, **а I – все остальные**?

Comment: Ну, может быть, и вправду это случай для мини-нововведения.